# Retriofit Url Querying

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit for networking in my Books Android application.

Here is the query URL.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=subject:android
```

I want to ask how can I use it in retrofit as it contains colon at the end and I don't know how to do it. I'm new to it. How do I get (subject: android) at the end of it? I searched for it online but didn't find any solution.

I searched retrofit documentation but didn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

Try, using `@Path` annotation

```
@GET(books/v1/volumes?q=subject:{subject})
Call<ResponseBody> getBooks(@Path String subject);
```

Comment: Not working showing error.  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "q=subject:{subject}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `@Query`.

**Interface**:

```
public interface NetworkService {
    @GET("books/v1/volumes")
    Call<ResponseBody> getSubject(@Query(value = "q") String subjectName);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public static final String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/";

// onCreate()
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
NetworkService client = retrofit.create(NetworkService.class);

Call<ResponseBody> call = client.getSubject("subject:android");
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>()...);
```

### OR

`@QueryMap`.

**Interface**:

```
public interface NetworkService {
    @GET("books/v1/volumes")
    Call<ResponseBody> getSubject(@QueryMap() Map<String, String> queryMap);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public static final String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/";

// onCreate()
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
NetworkService client = retrofit.create(NetworkService.class);

Map<String, String> subjectMap = new HashMap<>();
subjectMap.put("q", "subject:android");

Call<ResponseBody> call = client.getSubject(subjectMap);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>()...);
```

**Optional**:

You can specify whether the parameter name and value are already URL encoded.

When set to `true`: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=subject:android".

When `false` (default): "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=subject%3Aandroid".

```
Call<ResponseBody> getSubject(@Query(value = "q", encoded = true) String subjectName); // for @Query
Call<ResponseBody> getSubject(@QueryMap(encoded = true) Map<String, String> queryMap); // for @QueryMap
```